# Is this sentence well constructed?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

It is a subtopic of article about AI

> WHY THE RECENT INTEREST IN AI SAFETY

It seems to me there is no verbs here.
I would be grateful if you explain what structure is used here
[link to the website](https://futureoflife.org/background/benefits-risks-of-artificial-intelligence/?cn-reloaded=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WHY THE RECENT INTEREST IN AI SAFETY

This is a common way titles are written to save space.

In the actual text, it should be something like 'Why is there a recent interest in AI safety?'

Comment: Also punctuation can be omitted in headlines, titles, etc.